# Responsive font size in MS Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook, inline

I would like to make the font size responsive in my email signature. VW is exactly what I need, but doesn't appear to work in outlook.  I've tried css, but I believe it needs to be inline CSS, and I'm not sure how to incorporate @media screen inline.

I've tried em, this also doesn't resize.

```
<body style="padding:0; margin:0">
<table width="700" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="700" valign="top">
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="700">
<tr>
<td align="left" width="30%" style="vertical-align:bottom";>
<img src="https://grapaes.com/signatures/Grapa%20and%20tag.png? 
_t=1563094564" alt="Logo" border="0" style="display:block" /></td>
<td style="width: 70%;  height:auto; vertical-align:bottom;">
<span style="font-size: 1vw; font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif, Arial; 
color: #9d2347; font-weight: bold;">Full Name</span><br />
<span style="font-size: .9em; font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif, Arial; 
color: #5f6062; font-weight: 300;">Job descrtiption</span><br />
span style="font-size: .85em; font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif, Arial; 
color: #5f6062; font-weight:300;">Phone: number here<br />
Website: <a href="http://www.grapaes.com"><font color="5f6062">
```

website/u>

```
</div>
</body>
```

It doesn't look terrible on mobile, but the font is just a tad too small, and nothing I do seems to increase it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this on another thread on Stackoverflow, why I couldn't find it before I posted the question, I'm not sure:

font-size: calc(7px + .5vw);

This syntax worked, and finally allowed me to have scalable text.  It can be easily read in mnobile now.

Answer (score 0):

The `overflow-x` CSS element is not supported in Outlook. You can find supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties described in the following articles:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12))
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338200(v=office.12))

Outlook uses Word as an email editor for displaying your HTML markup. So you should follow to rules defined for Word if you want to get a nice view.

Comment: This is an interesting resource, thank you.  I'm afraid that I've also found Outlook doesn't follow CSS, unless it's inline, which is why I'm having a hard time with the responsive text.